# Access Token Scope in Azure AD and Power BI Government

Tags: powerbi, azure-web-app-service, single-sign-on, powerbi-embedded

I currently have Power BI embedded with SSO, I do this with an app registered in Azure, using the JavaScript libraries (msal, power BI client). However, now that I have tried this implementation for government power BI, it is not working, In the app registered in Azure **I only see power BI service (public)**.

I was checking the documentation and I figured out that the API scope is different between the Power BI public and Power BI government.
[current Api from Azure app registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym2P2.png)
Power BI Government URL: https://analysis.usgovcloudapi.net/powerbi/api/.defaul

How can I add the scope for Power BI Government in the app registered in Azure?

Comment: If you have any queries, Need to provide more specific information

Answer (score 0):

Scopes can be passed as a parameter in the request when you're signing using msal. Refer to this [Single sign-on with msal](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso) and see the scopes in the request they are passing in the msalInstance.